# How to combine two models in Django view

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have this code in my views.py

I just want to combine the (studentenrollment query) and (scheduleofpayment query)

```
gradelevel = request.GET.get('gradelevel')
semester = request.GET.get('semester')
payment = request.GET.get('payment')

studentenrollment = StudentsEnrollmentRecord.objects.filter(Education_Levels=gradelevel).filter(Semester =semester).filter(Payment_Type=payment)
scheduleofpayment = ScheduleOfPayment.objects.filter(Education_Levels=gradelevel).filter(Payment_Type = payment).filter(Semester=semester)
```

How do i combine this two model in 1 queryset?

```
class ScheduleOfPayment(models.Model):
    GradeLevel_Category= models.ForeignKey("gradelevel_category", on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    Education_Levels = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel,  on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    Semester = models.ForeignKey("semestral", related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    Courses = models.ForeignKey(Course,  on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    Payment_Type = models.ForeignKey(PaymentType,  on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    Date = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    Amount = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

class StudentsEnrollmentRecord(models.Model):
    Student_Users = models.ForeignKey(StudentProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    School_Year = models.ForeignKey(SchoolYear,  on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Courses = models.ForeignKey(Course,  on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Track")
    strands = models.ForeignKey("N_strand", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Section = models.ForeignKey(Section,  on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,blank=True)
    Payment_Type = models.ForeignKey(PaymentType,  on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True ,blank=True)
    Discount_Type = models.ForeignKey(Discount, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,blank=True)
    Education_Levels = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    Semester = models.ForeignKey("semestral", on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
```

and in my html

```
{% for obj **Combination of two queryset**%}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: How are you planning to join these two? The only way I can see is by using these fields that exist on both: `Semester`, `Education_Levels` and `Payment_Type`. Can you tell us a bit more about your desired outcome?

Comment: can you please show me on how to combine those two? using Semester  and Payment_Type?

Comment: Can't do it exactly now, but I'll have a look later. Don't know why someone downvoted you, I'll upvote as I don't see why this isn't a well made question.

Comment: okay mr @BernardoDuarte ill wait, and thank you :)